# Cannot copy data from one GridView to anther ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am newbie in C# ASP.NET, my project consist of 2 GridViews , the first GridView displays data from SQL server, and it works fine.
Now what I need to implement is that, when we select any row from gridView 1, the rows should be copied to GridView 2.

Below is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=x;Integrated Security=True");
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from BookDetails", sc);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sd.Fill(ds, "BookDetails");
        sc.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }


 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            GridView.Rows.Add(row);
            GridView.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
    }
```

GridView.Rows.Add(row); //error
 GridView.Rows.Remove(row); //error
displays the values of data source in a table in each column represents a field and each row represents a record

Comment: Not to mention that you probably don't want to add the same row multiple times if a row becomes selected more than once. Also you should avoid using select *, be explicit. My guess is you are just missing a namespace reference in the using at the top of your class. Or you could add the namespace in your loop.

Comment: @SeanLange am newbie can u provide the modify the codes. Thank you

Comment: Are you really using ASP.NET.  DataGridView and DataGridViewRow are Windows.Forms things.  In addition, "DataGridView.SelectedRows" is trying to access a static property named SelectedRows from the DataGridView class, not an instance property.
What type is GridView1 (i'm guessing it's GridView and not DataGridView)

Comment: @Flydog57 its gridView asp.net C#

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you dont need to loop though each row at all. Because you already know the selected row. Try using something like:

```
GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
GridView2.DataSource = row;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

By the way, the following code will help you to loop through each row:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
........                
}
```

Comment: check modified codes and the erros that displays plz.

Comment: why did u deleted the for each codes. plz edit your codes.

Comment: i got this error when applied your codes.    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
            GridView2.DataSource = row;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }                       //error   "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."

Answer (score 0):

Use this it may helps you.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdValue" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnMove" runat="server" Text="Move" OnClick="btnMove_Click" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="gridView2" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**c# code**

```
private void BindGridView()
    {
        if (Session[key] == null)
        {
            gridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();
            gridView1.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            gridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session[key];
            gridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }

protected DataTable GetDataSource()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int)).AutoIncrement = true;
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
            DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[2];
            keys[0] = dt.Columns["ID"];
            dt.PrimaryKey = keys;
            dt.Rows.Add("1", "first object", 34);
            dt.Rows.Add("2", "second object", 24);
            dt.Rows.Add("3", "third object", 34);
            dt.Rows.Add("4", "fourth object", 24);
            dt.Rows.Add("5", "fifth object", 34);

            Session[key] = dt;
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

protected void btnMove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtMain = Session[key] as DataTable;
            //copy the schema of source table
            DataTable dtClone = dtMain.Clone();
            foreach (GridViewRow gv in gridView1.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chk = gv.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
                HiddenField hdValue = gv.FindControl("hdValue") as HiddenField;
                if (chk.Checked)
                {
                    //get only the rows you want
                    DataRow[] results = dtMain.Select("ID=" + hdValue.Value + "");
                    //populate new destination table
                    foreach (DataRow dr in results)
                    {
                        dtClone.ImportRow(dr);
                    }
                }
                gridView2.DataSource = dtClone;
                gridView2.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            BindGridView();
        }

    }
```

Comment: do i add checkbox inside the gridview?

Comment: yes, you can select the multiple records and you can move those into another grid

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this[image]

```
int x = 0;// this must be placed obove the dataGridView1_SelectionChanged 
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    {
        this.dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
        this.dataGridView3.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        x++;

    }
}
```

Comment: am not using windows form , am using ASP.net C#.