# Add selected rows from one GridView to another GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to add the selected rows from one GridView to another GridView in ASP.NET C#.

So the code i was implemented on my project to copy selected rows from one Grid to another Grid.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=x;Integrated Security=True");
        sc.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from BookDetails", sc);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sd.Fill(ds, "BookDetails");
        sc.Close();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }




    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        GridView2.DataSource = row; //error here
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

when i run the project i got an error (GridView2.DataSource = row;)  :-
 "Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."

[Image of what i need to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BN0l9.png)

[error of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIbSV.png)

Comment: You need to set the data source to a data set (or data table), not just one row. If it's already bound, add the row to the source it's bound to.

Comment: @Nikki9696 plz can u modify my codes because am newbie in C# asp.net.

Comment: Where is your code that binds GridView2.DataSource initially?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I don't know how to do it. thats why am asking from u to modify the codes to get an idea.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: @Nikki9696 yes. its a school assignment

Comment: Do your homework  ;)

Comment: @Nikki9696 am trying to do it. even real world programmers asking questions and looking for help some times.

Comment: I'm not doing you any favors by just writing it for you with no explanation. That's why SO folks won't usually do people's homework for them. You should watch a tutorial and see WHY things work as they do. This looks promising, but ask your teacher for help so he/she can explain if you don't understand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E64rFg3Q1PI

Comment: Also, the documentation these days doesn't suck so much and has examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: am not hacving too much time. I need this to be done today. after u applied your codes. And after submission am going to understand the whole project by my own on free time.

Comment: Did you seriously create a new account and ask the EXACT same question a second time??? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51213693/cannot-copy-data-from-one-gridview-to-anther-asp-net-c-sharp#comment89408503_51213693 Or do you two have the same class together?

Comment: omg, this is my friend having same assignment.

Comment: Perhaps the two of you should work together. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange he in different class groups :)

Comment: @SeanLange i need lil help brother plz contact me m.hassan.y1994@gmail.com

Comment: NO that is now how SO works. I am not your free consultant where you get help.

Comment: @Sean Lange u get paid than.

Comment: Not going to happen mate. How are you going to learn this if you just pay somebody else to do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typecasting "row" to be "IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource."? If that doesnt work, it may be because GridView2.DataSource can only be IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource thus meaning it simply isn't possible. I don't fully understand what you're trying to do in the function "GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1".

Comment: i need to click select row from gridView1 , than it will add selected row to gridView 2